# How to pass a kinect image frame to a Qt label?

Tags: c++, qt, kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm using the Kinect SDK and Qt toolkit to make a application that shows the depth frame in a GUI window. For a normal opencv camera image i use to do this:

```
qimage = QImage(image.data, 640, 480, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(qimage);
    ui.DepthView->adjustSize();
```

But with the Kinect sdk this doesn't work. When i grab a frame like this:

```
hr = m_pNuiSensor->NuiImageStreamGetNextFrame(m_pDepthStreamHandle, 
1000, &imageFrame);
```

I can't convert it to an Qimage. I also tryed to use the texture after grabbing the frame:

```
hr = m_pNuiSensor->NuiImageFrameGetDepthImagePixelFrameTexture(m_pDepthStreamHandle,
&imageFrame, &nearMode, &pTexture);
```

And then i tryed to convert the pTexture to a Qimage, but that doesn't work either.

I cleary do something wrong here, can anybody give me some pointers with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have one year old questions which are not accepted... why should anyone help you?

Comment: What doe you mean by not accepted? What am i doing wrong then?

Comment: @UmNyobe Your are totally right. Some how i didn't get the accet system. I found accepted all the great answers on my onld questions. Thx for the notice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the value of image.data preserved?
It must remain valid until the QImage is no longer in use...